# 13 ram available out of 16 when nothing is running

Tags: 20.04, ram

I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I have 16GB Ram. When I use `free -h` I see the following, why is that?

[My Ram Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ggM1.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: 1 GB is probably used for your GPU, everything else is clear from the output.

Comment: You can use the "top" command to see the topmost resource consuming processes running. There, you can use shift-m to sort by memory.